# Estimating the range of $1$'s in an array of $0$'s and $1$'s

Tags: algorithms, survey-sampling

I have a large array $A$ that contains something like $[0..1..0..]$. It has a continuous range of $0$'s, followed by a range of $1$'s, and then another range of $0$'s.

This array is large and access is expensive, so I want to use a sampling algorithm to estimate the range $(i, j)$, where $A_i$ is the first $1$ and $A_j$ is the last $1$. Let's say I want to approximate this within an error of $\epsilon n$ where $n$ is the size of $A$, so that I get a range $(i', j')$ where $|i' - i| \leq \epsilon n$ and $|j' - j| \leq \epsilon n$.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there some information on minimum size of the run of 1's (or on the maximum size of either run of 0s)? If there can be as few as a single 1, and it can be anywhere from position 2 to position n-1, it is going to be slow to find.

Comment: Are you *certain* this array has such a structure and, for instance, doesn't violate the conditions at a small random number of locations?  And are you *certain* that when you access it you obtain the correct value with no chance of error?  Do you need to locate the range at all, or would it acceptable--when $|i-j|$ is small--not to find any ones?